# Reading fields from multiple instances of the same Fragment class

Tags: android, android-fragments

Let's say I have the classes MainActivity, NestedDialogFragment. Both classes have a form, handled by the same FormAdapter. When a button is pressed in MainActivity's form, its FormAdapter creates a new NestedDialogFragment.In the same way, an instance of NestedDialogFragment can press a button and create another instance of NestedDialogFragment.

So, if I have:

```
MainActivity --(FormAdapter)--> NestedDialogFragment(1) --(FormAdapter)--> NestedDialogFragment(2)
```

How can I, inside NestedDialogFragment(2), read/change a field from NestedDialogFragment(1).

Answer (score 0):

You can use buses to do it.
Look at:

- https://github.com/beworker/tinybus
- https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus

Comment: Thanks! I'm not sure I can use tools like this one on company code, though. Is there a solution native to Android?